# Generalize date formate in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, date-format

I am working MVC (Razor) application. In view, I am getting date from my database in different formate but I have to show date only in "MM/DD/YY" formate in my view. How can I do it. 
Could you please suggest, What I can use for it.

Comment: -1, You don't have the minimum benevolence to read msdn or at least google date time formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you can annotate the field with this property

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
```

and give it any format string you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string NewDate = YourDateObject.ToString("MM/DD/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom  `Data Annotations Model MetadataProvider` to achieve this

1. Create custom `Data Annotations Model MetadataProvider` buy inherting `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` as follows:

   ```
   public class JobMetaDataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
   {
   protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
   {
       var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
       if (modelType == typeof(DateTime))
           metadata.EditFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}";

       return metadata;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Then in your `Global.asax` specify your `Metadata Provider`

   ```
       protected void Application_Start()
       {
       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
       RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
       RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
       ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new JobMetaDataProvider(); \\specify your Metadata Provider
       }
   ```